# Passing an integer variable from C# to Microsoft SQL server and then comparing the retrieved data

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to develop a CBIR application and thus I am taking an input image, calculating its RGB values in three different variables and modifying the values, then storing them in three variables: `r1`, `g1`, `b1`.

Then I am trying to pass these values to database so that I can retrieve images by comparing them using comparison operators, but I am unable to get any data, though I think I am using parameters in a right way.

Here is my code:

```
double r1, r2, g1, g2, b1, b2;
r1 = aveR -(.1 * aveR);
r2 = aveR +(.1 * aveR);
g1 = aveG -(.1 * aveG);
g2 = aveG +(.1 * aveG);
b1 = aveB -(.1 * aveB);
b2 = aveB +(.1 * aveB);

cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HOME;Initial Catalog=test_image;Integrated Security=True");
cmd = new SqlCommand("select path from image where red BETWEEN @r1 AND   @r2 AND green BETWEEN @g1 AND @g2 AND blue BETWEEN @b1 AND @b2" , cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@r1", r1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@r2", r2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g1", g1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g2", g2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b1", b1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b2", b2);
cn.Open();

SqlDataReader dr;
try
{
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 9; 
        listBox1.Items.Add(dr["path"].ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    cn.Close();
}

/*after this i dont get any data in my list box, where i am expecting the paths of image("path" col in my DB) which should be returned after the comparison query.*/
```

Here is the code that populates (hope I don't get it wrong, i.e. this code takes the images one by one and then inserts them into the database).

```
int width = 256;
int height = 128;
int sumr = 0, sumg = 0, sumb = 0;
int rank = 0;
openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Images|*.jpg; *.bmp; *.png; *.gif";
DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

listBox1.Items.Add("Pixel          RED            GREEN      BLUE ");
listBox2.Items.Add("avgR     avgG   avgB   ");


if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach(string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
    {
        try
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(file);
            Image img1 = Resizeimage(img, width, height);

            pictureBox1.Image = img1;
            textBox1.Text = file;

            Bitmap img2 = new Bitmap(img1);
            Color c;

            for (int i = 0; i < img2.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < img2.Height; j++)
                {
                    c = img2.GetPixel(i, j);
                    int r = Convert.ToInt16(c.R);
                    int g = Convert.ToInt16(c.G);
                    int b = Convert.ToInt16(c.B);

                    sumr = sumr + r;
                    sumg = sumg + g;
                    sumb = sumb + b;

                    listBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString() + "   " + r.ToString() + "    " + g.ToString() + "   " + b.ToString());
                }
            }

            int total = img2.Height * img2.Width;
            int aveR = sumr / total;
            int aveG = sumg / total;
            int aveB = sumb / total;

            listBox2.Items.Add(aveR.ToString() + "   " + aveG.ToString() + "  " + aveB.ToString());

            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HOME;Initial   Catalog=test_image;Integrated Security=True");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            byte[] pic_arr = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(pic_arr, 0, pic_arr.Length);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into image(path,image,red,green,blue,rank)values(@path,@image,@red, @green, @blue, @rank)", con);              


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", pic_arr);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@red", aveR);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@green", aveG);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blue", aveB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rank", rank);
            con.Open();
            try
            {
               int rs = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               if (rs > 0)
               {
                     MessageBox.Show("image stored successfully");
               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("cannot display the image"+ ex.Message);
        }

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
    }
  }
}       

public static Image Resizeimage(Image img, int width, int height)
{
    Image newimg = new Bitmap(width, height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newimg);

    g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    return newimg;
}

/** I am sorry if braces make you all little upset, I am new to this site, so editing might be poor**/
```

Comment: Can you add the code that populates the database?

Comment: What if you build the command using StringBuilder rather than parameters?  Same results?

Comment: here is the code which takes the path and then insert images one by one into the database...

Comment: What is type of red, green and blue columns in Image table in your DB ? Is it possible that no record match condition in where clause ?

Comment: Have you run a command through something like Management Studio to confirm whether you get results back or not? Have you put a break point in your code to confirm that your datareader is empty (you say that your list is empty at the end but not whether you actually confirmed that the datareader was empty). You should be able to narrow down where your problem is a bit by testing easily enough. And of course you can use a stored procedure to make testing a bit easier...